# PHP if statememt to check available places

Tags: php

I am trying to check if there is available places to book an activity and I'm using if statement to do so. If statement checks if bookedPlaces are less than total number of places available and if there is available places it should allow to book and insert into clientEvent and  update bookingPlaces in the activityEvent table. If there is no available places it should echo Fully Booked. It always echos that it is fully booked. I'm not sure how to insert and update in one quesry aswell.

```
<?php

session_start();
require("connection.php");

$con=mysqli_connect("$mysql_host","$mysql_user","$mysql_password","$mysql_database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql ="select bookedPlaces, noOfPlaces from activityEvent";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$clientID=$_SESSION['clientID'];
$activityEventID =$_SESSION['activityEventID'];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $booked =$row['bookedPlaces'];
    $noofPlaces = $row['noOfPlaces'];
}

if($booked < $noofPlaces)
{
    echo "You have booked ";
    $sql="Insert into clientEvent(clientID, activityEventID) Values('$clientID','$activityEventID')";

    $sql= "update activityEvent set AvailablePlaces  = ($available -1) where activityEventID = $activityEventID";
    echo "$sql";
}
else
{
    echo "Fully booked ";
}

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your program logic. First, why do you loop trough results if you overwrite each time $booked ? What do you expect to be content of $booked variable? Next use var_dump and dump $booked and $noofPlaces and update your question with result.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an option: 
I suppose that some rows at bookedPlaces and noOfPlaces are null, so you have to compare them.
You can create a counter function like this:

```
function counter($row){
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "first");
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT({$row}) FROM records WHERE {$row} !='' ");  // !=0 or !=[what's your no value]
$row = $res->fetch_row();
return $row[0];
}
```

Now you can use

```
if(counter('bookedPlaces') < counter('noOfPlacest') {
```

In this option, leave your fetch_assoc query as it is.

Comment: Thank you for the help, if i do this it does not give any errors and it does what I want to do it but it does not insert or update the database. It only check and tells if its booked or not. Do you know how could I fix this? @Nikos

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the entire if-else block `if($booked < $noofPlaces)` is outside of your `while` loop. So, the `if` statement is evaluating unexpected values.

The corrected code should look like this.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $booked = $row['bookedPlaces'];
    $noofPlaces = $row['noOfPlaces'];

    if ($booked < $noofPlaces) {
        echo "You have booked ";
        $sql = "Insert into clientEvent(clientID, activityEventID) Values('$clientID','$activityEventID')";
        $sql = "update activityEvent set AvailablePlaces  = ($available -1) where activityEventID = $activityEventID";
        echo "$sql";
    }
    else {
        echo "Fully booked ";
    }
}
```